# 404 Not found. and Dont update

Tags: updates

[image]

I dont know how to use this forum. I faced a big problems. I search a lot but cant me at all. I took a screenshot. Once I have install Miktex. It just down my terminal. please help me. I don't need Miktex.
The errors is

````
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]```
``` Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (43.255.166.254), connection timed out
Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
````

Comment: 1st problem: You added a few PPAs that aren't for your release. Remove them all. 2nd problem: Unlike with the 1st one where the error is expected it seems you have also problems connecting to the Ubuntu official repos. (Maybe) 3rd problem: Why do you have "backports" enabled? Enable it only if you have a good reason.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me how to fix them all. I am absolutely beginner in Ubuntu..

Comment: Easy way is opening Software & Updates > Other software and remove the PPAs you added and are giving errors. You may want also to change the server to the main one (2nd problem) and I don't need to tell you how to disable "backports" since you did it yourself so you must know how to undo.